# How to prevent any event from continuing after clicking on an element (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to experiment on creating something where you can rate by no. of stars. However, after I click on the rating I want and the number of stars has been printed out, I can still click on the stars and change the value. How can I stop all events after I click?

This is the jsFiddle demo of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/3pMuy/

Comment: If you define the click() function handler  inside the hover() handler, you'll get multiple click handlers - which is bad.

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky I'm sorry but I'm new to jQuery. What does that mean? Do I create a separate function outside it?

Comment: yes. also, I believe the click handler should be attached to the <a> elements, and not the <li>s. e.g. $('ul li').bind('hover', function, function).children('a').bind('click', function);

Comment: That has nothing to do with jQuery, it's a logic error. Every time you hover over one of the elements, you adding a new click event handler. The event handlers are not overridden, they are *added*. So after you hovered twice over one element, you have two click event handlers on the element, which both get triggered when you click (but they do the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.one` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/one/). The event handler bound with this will only be executed once.

Answer (score 2):

The flag suggestion is not to bad.
This will do the trick for you.

Not the nicest soulution but.. hey check it out!

http://jsfiddle.net/3pMuy/21/

Answer (score 1):

Your code binds a jQuery event each time you hover a star, thats bad.

By the way, [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3pMuy/15/) is a solution for your version with an added line:

```
$('ul li').unbind("click").unbind("mouseenter").unbind("mouseleave");
```

I suggest you to consider moving the click binding outside the hover event and use `.one()`